# What is the difference between the "Normal" version and the "Large Heap" versions of OpenJDK with OpenJ9?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

In what scenarios would someone want the "Normal" version vs. the "Large Heap" version of the OpenJDK with OpenJ9?

What is the difference?

[A Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgerf.png)

Comment: [Are you looking to run a Java application with OpenJ9 that requires a large heap size (more than ~57GB)?](https://blog.openj9.org/2018/06/12/openj9-xl-heap/)

Comment: OpenJ9 can not do as hotspot: automatically choose the reference size bases on the size of the heap. Don't ask me why as I do not know. So they have _two_ builds : one _with_ compressed references and one _without_. That with compressed references can scale up to a max of 57GB of heap, the one where 64 bit references are used can take more than that.